# How to install ZFS on KDE neon?

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, zfs

The distro is based on Ubuntu xenial. In fact sources.list is the same as my Ubuntu setup. When I try to install ZFS via the normal Ubuntu way (sudo apt install ZFS), there's no zfs.ko.

Can you please help?

ps. I get the same issue of my laptop (HP 8640p) or using virtualbox.

edit:

I just installed the distro on a new virtualbox container. I tried both these ISOs: neon-userltsedition-20171011-0018-amd64.iso and neon-useredition-20171012-1018-amd64.iso.

Here are the steps I followed after the the installation completed (i.e. first boot)

step1: sudo apt update

step2: sudo apt full-upgrade

step3: sudo reboot now

step4: sudo apt install zfs (notice that using zfs package installs zfsutils-linux. Also Ubuntu recommends using zfs package for 16.xx versions: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ZFS)

```
chiyo@mydesktop1:~$ sudo apt install zfs
[sudo] password for chiyo:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree      
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'zfsutils-linux' instead of 'zfs'
Starting pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 0
Starting 2 pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 0
Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libnvpair1linux libuutil1linux libzfs2linux libzpool2linux zfs-doc zfs-zed
Suggested packages:
  default-mta | mail-transport-agent samba-common-bin nfs-kernel-server zfs-initramfs
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libnvpair1linux libuutil1linux libzfs2linux libzpool2linux zfs-doc zfs-zed
  zfsutils-linux
0 to upgrade, 7 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
Need to get 897 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2,902 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 zfs-doc all 0.6.5.6-0ubuntu18 [50.0 kB]
Get:2 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libuutil1linux amd64 0.6.5.6-0ubuntu18 [27.4 kB]
Get:3 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libnvpair1linux amd64 0.6.5.6-0ubuntu18 [23.5 kB]
Get:4 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libzpool2linux amd64 0.6.5.6-0ubuntu18 [384 kB]
Get:5 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libzfs2linux amd64 0.6.5.6-0ubuntu18 [106 kB]
Get:6 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 zfsutils-linux amd64 0.6.5.6-0ubuntu18 [276 kB]
Get:7 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 zfs-zed amd64 0.6.5.6-0ubuntu18 [29.7 kB]
Fetched 897 kB in 15s (57.5 kB/s)                                                    
Selecting previously unselected package zfs-doc.
(Reading database ... 142686 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../zfs-doc_0.6.5.6-0ubuntu18_all.deb ...
Unpacking zfs-doc (0.6.5.6-0ubuntu18) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libuutil1linux.
Preparing to unpack .../libuutil1linux_0.6.5.6-0ubuntu18_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libuutil1linux (0.6.5.6-0ubuntu18) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnvpair1linux.
Preparing to unpack .../libnvpair1linux_0.6.5.6-0ubuntu18_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnvpair1linux (0.6.5.6-0ubuntu18) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libzpool2linux.
Preparing to unpack .../libzpool2linux_0.6.5.6-0ubuntu18_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libzpool2linux (0.6.5.6-0ubuntu18) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libzfs2linux.
Preparing to unpack .../libzfs2linux_0.6.5.6-0ubuntu18_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libzfs2linux (0.6.5.6-0ubuntu18) ...
Selecting previously unselected package zfsutils-linux.
Preparing to unpack .../zfsutils-linux_0.6.5.6-0ubuntu18_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking zfsutils-linux (0.6.5.6-0ubuntu18) ...
Selecting previously unselected package zfs-zed.
Preparing to unpack .../zfs-zed_0.6.5.6-0ubuntu18_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking zfs-zed (0.6.5.6-0ubuntu18) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu9) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.8) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.10.0-37-generic
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu19) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Setting up zfs-doc (0.6.5.6-0ubuntu18) ...
Setting up libuutil1linux (0.6.5.6-0ubuntu18) ...
Setting up libnvpair1linux (0.6.5.6-0ubuntu18) ...
Setting up libzpool2linux (0.6.5.6-0ubuntu18) ...
Setting up libzfs2linux (0.6.5.6-0ubuntu18) ...
Setting up zfsutils-linux (0.6.5.6-0ubuntu18) ...
zfs-import-cache.service is a disabled or a static unit, not starting it.
zfs-import-scan.service is a disabled or a static unit, not starting it.
zfs-mount.service is a disabled or a static unit, not starting it.
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.8) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.10.0-37-generic
Setting up zfs-zed (0.6.5.6-0ubuntu18) ...
zed.service is a disabled or a static unit, not starting it.
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu9) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu19) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
chiyo@mydesktop1:~
```

step 6: looking for ZFS kernel modules

```
chiyo@mydesktop1:~$ sudo find / -iname "zfs.ko" -type f
chiyo@mydesktop1:~$ sudo find / -iname "spl.ko" -type f
/lib/modules/4.10.0-37-generic/kernel/zfs/spl/spl.ko
chiyo@mydesktop1:~$
```

step7: getting system info

```
chiyo@mydesktop1:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: neon
Description:    KDE neon LTS User Edition 5.8
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
chiyo@mydesktop1:~$ uname -a
Linux mydesktop1 4.10.0-37-generic #41~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 6 22:42:59 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
chiyo@mydesktop1:~$ apt list --installed | grep linux-image

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

linux-image-4.10.0-37-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.10.0-37.41~16.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-image-extra-4.10.0-37-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.10.0-37.41~16.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.10.0.37.39 amd64 [installed,automatic]
chiyo@mydesktop1:~$
```

Comment: It looks like zfs module is compiled into the kernel in Ubuntu linux-image-4.10.0-37-generic. This means that the functionality should be there without zfs.ko being present as a separate file.

Comment: @jpe on my official Ubuntu 16.04 installation, zfs.ko is present on the /lib/modules/linux-image-4.10.0-37-generic/kernel/zfs/zfs location

Comment: It seems that the kernel in KDE Neon LTS User Edition 5.8 installer squashfs that gets copied to the target system during install is missing proper zfs configuration. It is most probably a bug of the installer of KDE  neon LTS but you should check if it has been mentioned in the docs. Try to fix using `apt-get clean ; apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-generic linux-image`. The ubuntu image linux-image-4.10.0-37-generic_4.10.0-37.41~16.04.1_amd64.deb indeed has zfs.ko present.

Comment: @jpe that worked. Thanks you very much! :)